# Why Spring Authorization Server return "invalid_grant"?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to use Spring Authorization Server to protect my APIs in microservices. My APIs are being accessed via API Gateway Server. I have two Resource Server, 1 discovery server & 1 configuration server.

I'm following code from this [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html)

My Application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 9000

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: trace

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          oidc-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "oidc-client"
              client-secret: "{noop}secret"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "authorization_code"
                - "refresh_token"
              redirect-uris:
                - "http://127.0.0.1:8222/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client"
              post-logout-redirect-uris:
                - "http://127.0.0.1:8222/"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
                - "profile"
            require-authorization-consent: true
```

My Application Main File:

```
package com.ali.authserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Security Configuration file:

```
package com.ali.authserver.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("oidc-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8222/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8222/")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

}
```

My Log:

```
2024-03-12T01:59:07.618+05:00 TRACE 20452 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-03-12T01:59:07.618+05:00 TRACE 20452 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java:86) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.java:139) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.java:84) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcLogoutEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcLogoutEndpointFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationServerContextFilter.java:61) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]

2024-03-11T12:55:29.218+05:00 DEBUG 10104 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8222/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client&scope=openid+profile&continue to session
2024-03-11T12:55:29.220+05:00 DEBUG 10104 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@79b201d, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]
2024-03-11T12:55:29.221+05:00 DEBUG 10104 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@480c62cf
2024-03-11T12:55:29.222+05:00 DEBUG 10104 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/login
```

I begin by entering URL which redirect me to login page:

```
http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8222/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client&scope=openid+profile
```

Then, I grab code:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8222/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client?code=SCOfg4kD9itAXmNIDgDnFatFVrjXHx7dkRsljY-QEppoLZ4NZ_m094BPTqu4yhK5Ulil2UKea_rmMzdeSJijPasu5A4CYzoe8IVW6K74OHhIMby6D0EWfhmOv1_uWMWP
```

Then , I use postman to get access token but get "invalid_grant" error:
[image: PostMan]

I will be grateful if someone help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Per RFC 6749

> 4.1.3.  Access Token Request
>
> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by sending the
> following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
> request entity-body:
>
> grant_type
> REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "authorization_code".
>
> code
> REQUIRED.  The authorization code received from the
> authorization server.
>
> redirect_uri
> REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the
> authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and their
> values MUST be identical.
>
> client_id
> REQUIRED, if the client is not authenticating with the
> authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1.
>
> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
> in Section 3.2.1.

> invalid_grant
> The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
> code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
> invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
> URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
> another client.

In your case, it seems like you're missing `client_id` (oidc-client) and `client_secret`, making the grant invalid

Comment: No, I have used clientid in redirect url as well as in postman call . check this image: https://i.imgur.com/RfmcReV.png